# How to implement the key-value file operations in Qt

Tags: qt, file

I want store my configuration data as like "key"-"value". Lets say key=IP then value="192.136.10.11". So I have several such data to store in a file. I know the file seek, cursor movement and data read/write is very boring things. So I want to know is there anything in Qt like I will open a file. Then store a pair like - `putPair("IP","192.136.10.11");`. For retreive data it could be like something `getValue("IP");` and it should return me the value 192.136.10.11. I found this type of functionality in android.

Is there any such functionality in Qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For preferences like data, [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) may do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You instantiate a QSettings class with QSettings::IniFormat to store key-value pair in an .ini file.

> m_pApplicationSettings = new
>   QSettings(m_strDependenciesDirPath+"\iConConfig.ini",
>                                                          QSettings::IniFormat,
>                                                          this);

The values are stored as QVariants, So the values can be stored and accessed as below,

> m_pApplicationSettings->setValue("Temp
>   Dir Path", QDir::tempPath()+"\iCon");
>   m_pApplicationSettings->value("Temp
>   Dir
>   Path",QDir::tempPath()+"\iCon").toString();

Answer (score 1):

Sure. the [QSettings](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsettings.html) class implements this functionality.
You can use it to access a platforms standard INI file for your application or open your own file.